# Defining hyperparameter search space of regression problem with optuna

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, optuna

This [tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/corochann/optuna-tutorial-for-hyperparameter-optimization) shows how to solve a regression problem using sklearn and optimize the hyperparameters of a LightGBM model using Optuna. One thing I noticed immediately is that they don't normalize any of the parameters before training the regression model. Are there any reasons why normalization isn't required in this problem?

I'm also trying to pass arguments (no. nodes, no. layers, activation function, learning rate) to the `objective` function, described in section `2. Use "trial" module to define hyperparameters dynamically!`. I'm reading the [docs](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/10_key_features/002_configurations.html#sphx-glr-tutorial-10-key-features-002-configurations-py) and I'm confused on how to incorporate the hyperparameter search space into the `objective` function.

Comment: From what I see they are using gradient boosted trees and any tree methods are very robust to dealing with non-normalized data since split is calculated based on the highest entropy reduction, which is calculated separately for each feature. Normally for any tree methods you don't really need to normalize data.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

The first regression algorithm (Ordinary Least Squares) was developed without normalization in mind. In fact, most regression problems do not require any form of normalization because it can make the model harder to interpret. You should only normalize your data if your algorithm is very sensitive to outliers.

That said, LightGBM is a form of tree-based gradient boosting algorithm. Being tree-based, the cutoff points of each node are insensitive to monotonic transformations.

In other words, if *f(·)* is a monotonic function and *x* is the point that reduces the cost function the most, then *f(x)* is also the point that reduces the cost function the most.

By normalizing your independent variables, you are subtracting the mean from all observations and dividing by *n*. Thus, you are not changing the order of the feature's observed variables.